# mysql connector to java jar file

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jar

I am developing my project in java in eclipse for which I am trying to connect my project to mysql database and I am trying access the jar file but unable to do the same , i have downloaded the file from following address https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=13520 , yet only a zip file is obtained and while opening it, it shows another folder and on opening that- there is zip file and from that another zip file is found but no jar file  ..I searched that jar files can be in form of zip file so to add in eclipse i tried converted them into jar files I used both cmd and online converter to convert the zip file into jar file, yet unsuccessful..please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update version of jdk installed on your platform and later open the zip folder with "openwith" option and there will be java(TM) SE library kee this as default and you are good to go..!P.S.-This solution was for windows..!